# Using If statements to handle multiple conditions

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to write some code that calculates the phenotype of a given genotype.
I have declared the genes in the following code which has three options, for instance ee, Ee, and EE.

Certain combinations give certain colours. I am finally at the point where I can make the genes change an image at the top of the app, but I keep getting errors with my if statements.  I have tried using blabla.contains, arrays, etc

These are the combinations I am trying to get in my code:

1. chestnut: ext = ee
2. bay: ext = Ee or EE, ago = AA or Aa
3. black: ext =
   EE or Ee and ago = aa

My code:

```
var ext = String("ee")
var ago = String("aa")

func checkPicture() {
    if ext = "EE" || "Ee" && ago == "aa" {
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
        base = String("black")
    }
    if ago == "Aa" || "AA" && ext == "EE" || "Ee" {
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bay")
        base = String("bay")
        }
    if ext == "ee" {
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chestnut")
        base = String("chestnut")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all please don't create a string from a string, this is sufficient

```
let ext = "ee"
let ago = "aa"
```

Basically you have to evaluate each value separately for example

```
if (ago == "Aa" || ago == "AA") && (ext == "EE" || ext == "Ee") { ...
```

and use `if - else if`.

---

However this is a good example to use a `switch` with a tuple

```
func checkPicture() {
    switch (ext, ago) {
        case ("EE", "aa"), ("Ee", "aa"):
            baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
            base = "black"
        case ("EE", "AA"), ("Ee", "AA"), ("EE", "Aa"), ("Ee", "Aa"):
            baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bay")
            base = "bay"
        case ("ee", _):
            baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chestnut")
            base = "chestnut"

        default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: I came back to this project after summer holidays and it's nearing completion!  Using a switch statement worked MUCH better than an if statement :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `ago == "Aa" || "AA"` you have to specify what you comparing with: `ago == "Aa" || ago == "AA"`, and in some cases you misuse the assignment operator `=` instead of using the equal to operator `==`. To be sure that you'll enter on only one if add the `else if` statement:

```
func checkPicture() {
    if ext == "ee" {
        //            chestnut
    } else if ago == "aa" {
        //            black
    } else {
        //            bay
    }
}
```